# Macro software on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, screen, development, software

I wanna have a background software than can press a certain spot when the notification appears immediately. Is there any app that can do that? Or can I manually write an app and execute it on my iPad?

Comment: You might want to try softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible. Due to sandbox restrictions built in iOS.

Even if you develop your own app you can only press a certain spot in your own app. You don't have any access to other apps or the system itself.